# XPATH query optimization

Tags: xpath

i have the following xml file

```
<site>
  <people>
    <person id="person0">
      <emailaddress>0@concordia.ca</emailaddress>
    </person>
     <person id="person1">
      <emailaddress>1@concordia.ca</emailaddress>
    </person>
     <person id="person2">
      <emailaddress>2@concordia.ca</emailaddress>
    </person>
  </people>

  <closed_auctions>
    <closed_auction>
    <annotation>123</annotation>
    <seller person="person1"/>
    </closed_auction>
    <closed_auction>
    <annotation></annotation>
    <seller person="person2"/>
    </closed_auction>
     <closed_auction>
    <annotation></annotation>
    <seller person="person3"/>
    </closed_auction>
  </closed_auctions>
</site>
```

we have a list of people and a list of auctions, as you can see the seller part contains a reference to person id

I want to check all the closed_auction tags and if it has non empty annotation tag, i have to get the seller person id and print the email address of this seller ( of this person )

the current query looks like this:

/site/people/person[@id=/site/closed_auctions/closed_auction[annotation/text()]/seller/@person]/emailaddress/text()

this query is working well for small xml file size, but it never ends for large xml files.
(i think the problem is related to the nested xpath, but i cannot find any other way)

could you please suggest any improvement

Thank you

Comment: Run two queries instead of one?

Comment: Opening and ending tag mismatch: `seller`

Comment: Try xquery: `for $x in doc("input.xml")//person let $y:=root($x)//seller[@person=$x/@id] where $y/../annotation/text()!="" return $x/emailaddress/text()'`

Comment: XSLT offers a very efficient solution by using *keys*. Are you interested in an XSLT solution?

Comment: @kev thank you, do you think this will improve performance?, actually i run it and same same :(

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev can you provide me with the xslt query? actually i haven't used xslt for retrieving xml nodes before. Thank you

Comment: user1027364, Done. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to check all the closed_auction tags and if it has non empty
>   annotation tag, i have to get the seller person id and print the email
>   address of this seller ( of this person )

**Here is an efficient way of getting the wanted `emailaddress` elements with an XSLT transformation -- using a [key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kPersonById" match="person" use="@id"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "key('kPersonById',
          /*/closed_auctions/*[string(annotation)]/seller/@person)/emailaddress"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<site>
  <people>
    <person id="person0">
      <emailaddress>0@concordia.ca</emailaddress>
    </person>
     <person id="person1">
      <emailaddress>1@concordia.ca</emailaddress>
    </person>
     <person id="person2">
      <emailaddress>2@concordia.ca</emailaddress>
    </person>
  </people>

  <closed_auctions>
    <closed_auction>
    <annotation>123</annotation>
    <seller person="person1"/>
    </closed_auction>
    <closed_auction>
    <annotation></annotation>
    <seller person="person2"/>
    </closed_auction>
     <closed_auction>
    <annotation></annotation>
    <seller person="person3"/>
    </closed_auction>
  </closed_auctions>
</site>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<emailaddress>1@concordia.ca</emailaddress>
```